# Julia - How to get the minimum of each row of matrix?

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, julia

I tried to make that code but it get the value of the last index in the  row

```
function heuristicCalculate(distanceBetweenCities,numOfCities) 
#distanceBetweenCities is a 29*29 array 
#Use this function to calculate the tour length using nearest neighbor heuristic Lnn
mindist=zeros(29,1)
  for i=1:29
    for j=1:29
    mindist[i,1]=Base.minimum(distanceBetweenCities[i,j])
    end
  end
  mindist
  return Lnn, tau0
  #Lnn  tour length using nearest neighbor heuristic
  #tau0  a value representing the initial phermone amount =1/(n*Lnn)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution would probably be

```
mindist = minimum(distanceBetweenCities,2)
```

where the `,2` denotes the dimension over which the minimum is searched.